# How can I bypass this message on Windows Server 2022?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, automation, windows-server-2022

I got following cmd command and I want to start an `.exe` installer with this, but when I execute it the message after it pops up.

```
START "DSM-Agent setup..." /WAIT /D %PATH% InstallClient.exe
```

The message:

[image: Open File - Security Warning]

I already tried adding domains or something to the registry but nothing worked. This is in an automation script, so the message is very deal breaking. I hope someone can help me.

Additional Info: The `.exe` is on another server.

Comment: Unblock the file within the properties of the file, the file is blocked, due the security configuration of the server. Hopefully, you have permission from an Administrator to run the file, running an unauthorized application on my server wouldn’t be allowed and easily auditable

Comment: @Ramhound what do you mean specificly with unblock the file?

Comment: View the properties of the file, there is an Unblock button, click it. This dialog can also be displayed when security settings are turned up, and the file isn’t signed with a code signing certificate, trusted by Windows. Some background [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394734/this-file-is-in-a-location-outside-your-local-network)

Comment: @Ramhound ok i got it, i had to deactivate the  Internet Explorer Enhanced Security and now its working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the  Internet Explorer Enhanced Security  and the Registry entry will work.